# understand operator precedence

Tags: java, string, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

Was fixing bug in our code and found this weird function that was misbehaving:

```
private String calculate(String a, String b) {
    return a == null ? "" : a + a != null && b != null ? "\n" : "" + b == null ? "" : b;
}
```

Being in a rush, I just added some parenthesis to have it work like this:

```
private String calculatePar(String a, String b) {
    return a == null ? "" : a + (a != null && b != null ? "\n" : "") + (b == null ? "" : b);
}
```

By the way this is not the most elegant way of doing, but both are actually from the (simplified) test case example I wrote to figure things out.

Now I made some testing on the buggy first function and here is what I figured:

- if a==null, it will return "" (empty string)
- if a!=null and b == null it will return null
- else (if a and b are not null) it will return "\n"

Now the big question: how did this happen? I mean it is quite probable that the compiler did not place its own parenthesis the way it was intended by the original developer, but how can you get null as a result?

Comment: I see the question got migrated and you got an answer; excellent! In the future, keep in mind this is the best place to ask this kind of question, as opposed to [CodeReview.se]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a matter more of operator precedence rather concatenation.  With no parentheses the compiler use the [Operator Precedence table](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) to judge evaluation order.  + has a higher precedence than the comparisons so the statement gets evaluated as

```
return a == null 
       ? "" 
       : (a + a != null && b != null) 
            ? "\n" 
            : ("" + b == null) 
                ? "" 
                : b;
```

Note: I would always indent nested ternary operator statements as an aid to comprehension.

**Step 1:** 
a == null 
 return ""

**Step 2:** 
a != null

Check
   (a + a != null && b != null)

(a+a != null) is always true so we are really testing b!= null

b!= null,

return "\n"

**Step 3:**

if b == null

Check
    ("" + b == null)

"" + b (null)  will never be equal to null; always false

so, return b, which is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have edited the title for further reference ;)